# Select the top n percent contributing rows from a sql table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like this,

```
c1    c2    c3
A     B     12
A     C     15
A     D     8
X     P     8
X     Q     12
X     R     15
```

Now I want to select those rows of top contributing (top 50 percent contributor for sum of c3 values, ex: 12 and 15 has contribution more than 50 percent of 12,15 and 8) c2 values for each c1 values. So the output would look like,

```
c1    c2    c3
A     B     12
A     C     15
X     Q     12
X     R     15
```

I am looking for best sql way to implement is.

Comment: You're tagged with 3 different databases.  Which one are you actually using here?

Comment: anything should be fine. bigquery is preferable.

Comment: That's not fine.  You should tell us the database.  Syntax always varies across databases.

Comment: I got your point as I want to understand the logic, I tagged different databases to most people can view this question.

Comment: @Kallol doing this with `SQL` tag is not appropriate, this violate the guideline and may cause your question get downvote, which make your point of getting more view  really weak. so just don't do this, choose the tag you want the most and include others in question.

Comment: Also, as mentioned, solutions could vary wildly depending on the RDBMS *and* version. So pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PERCENTILE_CONT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percentile_cont) for BigQuery:

```
WITH data as (
  SELECT 'A' AS c1, 'B' AS c2, 12 AS c3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'C', 15 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'D', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'P', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'Q', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'R', 15
)
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, PERCENTILE_CONT(c3, 0.5) OVER(PARTITION BY c1) AS median
  FROM data
)
WHERE c3 >= median
```

[image]